# Vue - Keep input focused on route change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a `TopNavBar` component, that is present on every route. This component includes a search input field. When a user clicks on the input field the route changes from `/bar` to `/foo` but input focus is lost. How can I (re)focus on the input?

TopNavBar.vue

```html
<template>
   <input type="search" name="search-library" v-focus ref="searchInput" @focus="initSearch". />
</template>

<script setup>
const searchInput = ref(null);

<input type="search" name="search-library" v-focus ref="searchInput" @focus="initSearch". />

function initSearch() {
  if (router.currentRoute.value.name != "/foo") {
    router.push({ path: "/foo", query: { initSearch: true }, key: route.fullPath });
  }
}

watch(
  () => router.currentRoute.value.path,
  (newRoute) => {
    if (newRoute == "/foo") {
      searchInput.value.focus();
    }
  }
);
</script>
```

I'm using Vue3 and Nuxt3. `v-focusz  directive is declared globally in` /plugins` folder and works as expected.

**Update**

`TopNavBar` is inside Nuxt 3 layout. Also, upon further investigation I've realised that the input does focus on route change but immediately loses it again.

Comment: have you confirmed that `searchInput.value.focus();` actually runs? if so, try running it inside a `nextTick` - personally, I hate `nextTick`, but sometimes it's necessary

Comment: Can confirm that ```searchInput.value.focus();``` runs. I've tried it with ```nextTick``` too but input still doesn't focus.

Comment: hmm, that's disappointing - as a *hack* (just to test something) what if you `setTimeout(searchInput.value.focus, 100)`

Comment: ```setTimeout(searchInput.value.focus, 100)``` throws a ```Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation``` error. ```setTimeout(searchInput.value.focus(), 100)``` doesn't seem to work either: Input has focus for a split second but loses it again right away.

Comment: yeah sorry ... was supposed to be `setTimeout(()=>searchInput.value.focus(), 100)`

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure but there should be a way to track those kind of things (focus lost) thanks to browser's devtools IMO. Pretty sure you can get a flash or alike, like when something re-renders etc. Again, not sure exactly where to find that one but it may be useful to debug, especially considering how an universal app like Nuxt works.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `$refs`, Attach a reference on input element and then call focus method on it.

In template:

```html
<parent-component>
  <search-component ref="searchComponentRef" />
</parent-component>
```

In script:

```js
mounted() {
  this.$refs.searchComponentRef.$el.focus();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this too with the same result: Input field focuses only for a fraction of a second and then loses focus. ```onMounted(() => {
  if (route.name === "/foo") {
    searchInput.value.focus();
  }
});```

Comment: I have completely failed to mention that the text input is inside a Nuxt layout - in case that makes a difference